# elasticsearch how do i query (search) in single document?

Tags: elasticsearch

assuming that index's name is index & document 1's id is "1"

how can i query in single document?

something like this..

```
GET index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "id": "1",
      "terms": ["is this text in document 1?"]
   }
}
```

or

```
GET index/_doc/1/_search
{
    ...
}
```

far as i found,

```
GET test/_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms" : {
            "_id" : ["1"]
        }
    }
}
```

this will get the document id of "1", but cannot perform any further queries.

the reason i want to query inside single document is because my app is using live-news view
and once news is retrieved from server, i want to search it in elasticsearch for keywork higlighting, and spam filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compose your query with [Boolean Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

The best approch is to specify the id query under the filter because it will not have effect on scoring. You can next specify queries under must, must_not and should, according to your need :

```
GET index/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {"_id": ["1"]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```